# How to plot Trigonometric Functions in an Excel Spreadsheet?

Tags: trigonometry

I have been given the silly task of plotting some trigonometric functions in MS Excel.  My task is to plot Sine, Cosine and Tangent on the same set of axes.

Now, I get the Sine and Cosine waves right, but Tan is giving me some problems.

All my angles have been converted to Radians in the Formula bar, and all the plots on the actual graph seem to be correct.

Is there a way I can select which parts of the function I want to show? Or maybe a way I can show asymptotes instead of having the points connected?

(Note, my final product should look like the sample picture, also in the attached picture of what I have done)

[What I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYB66.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a more continuous looking diagram you have to divide the interval into to more interval steps. My interval steps are 0.1 degree. The first rows 
are

```
degree      sin(x)      cos(x)           tan(x)
0       0               1                0
0,1     0,001745328     0,999998477     0,001745331
0,2     0,003490651     0,999993908     0,003490673
0,3     0,005235964     0,999986292     0,005236036
0,4     0,00698126      0,999975631     0,00698143
0,5     0,008726535     0,999961923     0,008726868
0,6     0,010471784     0,999945169     0,010472358
0,7     0,012217001     0,99992537      0,012217913
0,8     0,01396218      0,999902524     0,013963541
0,9     0,015707317     0,999876632     0,015709255
1       0,017452406     0,999847695     0,017455065
1,1     0,019197442     0,999815712     0,019200981
1,2     0,02094242      0,999780683     0,020947014
1,3     0,022687334     0,999742609     0,022693175
```

Only every 150th value has to be displayed on the x-axis. The table has 3,601 rows. Then the diagram looks like

[image]

The easiest way to select specific parts of the function (diagram) is to use a snipping tool.